# python iterable list comprehension in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to figure out why my nested list comprehension doesn't work. Code:

```
def myzip(*args):
    try:
        x = [iter(i) for i in [*args]]
        while True:
        # for i in range(5):
            yield [next(ii) for ii in x]
            # I want to know why the commented line below won't work
            # yield [next(ii) for ii in [iter(i) for i in [*args]]]
            # or why this outputs [1, 'a']
            # return [next(ii) for ii in [iter(i) for i in [*args]]]
    except:
        pass


def main():
    print(list(myzip([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['a', 'b', 'c'])))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

if I assign `[iter(i) for i in [*args]]` to `x` and then use this list comprehension `[next(ii) for ii in x]` everything works ok. and the output will be:

```
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]
```

But if I try to ommit variable `x` and do it in one bigger list comprehension (commented line) `[next(ii) for ii in [iter(i) for i in [*args]]]` it goes in infinite loop. If you replace infinite loop with the for loop (commented line), the output is:

```
[[1, 'a'], [1, 'a'], [1, 'a'], [1, 'a'], [1, 'a']]
```

Moreover, if I try `return [next(ii) for ii in [iter(i) for i in [*args]]]` it just returns:

```
[1, 'a']
```

Can someone tell me why is that?

Comment: Because every time you execute the `yield` statement it's creating a new list `[iter(i) for i in[*args]]`, which starts over instead of continuing where it left off.

Comment: But why is that?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? You're not saving the previous value anywhere, you're executing a brand new list comprehension.

Comment: It's like the difference between `for i in range(10):` and `while True: i = next(range(10))`

Comment: The second one creates a new range object each iteration and starts at the beginning.

Comment: Ok, my understanding was that it would create iterators (here `[iter(i) for i in [*args]]`) and then iterate through them in outer list comprehension. But instead it creates iterator each time in outer for loop? Is there a way to do it in "one line" (one big list comprehension)?

Comment: I don't think so, because you can't put `yield` inside a list comprehension.

Comment: What's the obsession with one-liners?

Comment: No obsession, I'm just curious

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

so i'm not going to answer your question directly (as the comments pretty well have this covered), but i am going to show how this can be done as a *horrible* one liner, just for fun:

```
def my_zip(*args):
    yield from iter(lambda data=[iter(a) for a in args]: [next(d) for d in data], None)
```

there are three parts.

- the first usage of `iter`, after `yield from`, creates a `callable_iterator`. this will repeat calling its first argument (the `lambda`) until it either sees its second argument (the sentinel value, in this case `None`) OR <s>it gets a `StopIteration` error</s> it encounters *any* exception. (in this case, it will be a `StopIteration` exception.
- in the `lambda` i have a default value for `data` which is a list of the iterators you want to iterate over. this gets created once, so each subsequent call to the function will reference this.
- finally, in the body of the `lambda`, i manually advance each of the iterators in `data` one time per function call. this will continue until one of the iterators is exhausted, at which point a `StopIteration` will be raised. <s>as you can see, in this case, the sentinel value doesn't matter because the first `iter` call will bail as soon as it gets its `StopIteration`</s> this will be bubbled up to the `list` consumer which causes it to, well, *stop iterating*. because of the exception, the sentinel value doesn't matter.

finally: please never actually do this in real code.

---

edit: some sample output

```
In [90]: list(my_zip('abcd', [1,2,3]))
Out[90]: [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]

In [91]: list(my_zip('abcd', [1,2,3,4,5,6]))
Out[91]: [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4]]
```

---

explanation edits: hat tip to @superb rain for their smart comments below.

Comment: How do you know the `callable_iterator` handles the `StopIteration`? I doubt it and I don't see it in the documentation.

Comment: I think it's the *consumer* of the iterator, not the iterator, that handles it. In this case `list`. If I'm not mistaken, it's the consumer that keeps asking the iterator for more and more values until it gets a StopIteration, at which point the consumer stops asking. For `list` I don't see it documented, but the [`for` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) talks about this.

Comment: actually, you're right! it's the `list` consumer that's catching the `StopIteration`, which makes sense. because it's how it knows to stop iterating over the thing it's consuming. i'll update my answer. good catch.

Comment: Ok :-). But how do you know that now? I *think* it's `list`, but I'm not sure. It could also be that *both* handle StopIteration, just `iter` then re-raising it (although I don't see why it would do that). And I can't think of a test to undoubtedly prove what exactly happens. Might require reading CPython source code and some background knowledge about that (in order to prove that something is *not* done by `iter`).

Comment: lol. for me, i'm happy with my mental model of `iter` raises everything eventually :). i realized i was being dumb in testing by wrapping in list and was like "let me try `next(iter(f, ...))` (where `f` just raises an exception) and see what happens. sure enough, you get all the exceptions i tested (`Exception, ValueError, StopIteration`)

Comment: Here's a demo showing that `iter` does *not* stop for every exception but may continue if asked to (otherwise the `3` wouldn't still get printed): https://repl.it/repls/MajesticMurkyClasslibrary#main.py

Comment: Aha! While my previous comment is right, trying that demo with StopIteration doesn't work. So here's one more test that shows that `iter` *does* catch `StopIteration`: https://repl.it/repls/TroubledUnlawfulAtom#main.py Two things to note there: 1) the iterator doesn't let us ask for further values after the StopIteration and 2) it raises a *different* StopIteration, not the one raised by `f`. Probably because iterators are [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) to keep raising StopIteration after the first one.

Comment: nice investigation! played around with both your code samples, and the second one was a good way to show what's actually happening. makes sense that it would catch the `StopIteration` to make sure the iteration doesn't continue beyond that point. thanks for digging in.